# Interpreting $\hat{e}_z$ in Maxwell's equations

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, notation

I'm trying to interpret a form of Maxwell's equations, but I can't seem to figure out where the term $\hat{e}_z$ comes from in the following equation:
$
\frac{\partial{\vec{E}_t}}{\partial{z}}+i\frac{\omega}{c}\hat{e}_z\times \vec{B}_t=\vec{\nabla}_tE_z
$

What does term usually mean?

Comment: It's the basis vector in the $z$-direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general note, asking notation questions without providing a reference to the original occurrence (from which we'd be able to infer the context) is an excellent recipe for an unanswerable question.

In this particular case, though, it's pretty clear that it refers to the unit basis vector in the $z$ direction,
$$\hat e_z=(0,0,1).$$
It arises in this context from calculating the curl $\nabla\times\mathbf B$ of a travelling plane wave in the $z$ direction, of the form $\mathbf B(\mathbf r,t)=\mathbf B_0e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$, but you'll need to work the details out yourself.